# If I posted a homebrew feature on this site, and plan to publish it (after revising based on feedback), what credits am I required to give?

Tags: support, copyright

I have not found any information about this on the website, but if I missed something blatant, please tell me.

I have posted numerous homebrew features on this website , and I have used advice gotten from this site to balance most of them. If, one day, I publish the subclass, would I be required to give any or all of the following credits?:

- To the website as a whole
- To the individual users that gave feedback
- Just to the users whose feedback I used

Or would I not be required to give any credit?

Comment: You might get better answers at [law.se]

Comment: Thank you. I am not that experience in .se sites. I posted it on the Law stack exchange: [If I posted a homebrew question on rpg.stackexchange.com and plan to publish it, what credits should I give?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64910/if-i-posted-a-homebrew-question-on-rpg-stackexchange-com-and-plan-to-publish-it)

Comment: At least related: [How would I cite a question or answer on RPG.SE as a source? Does this site fall under fair use?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2845/52137)

Comment: @NautArch it’s closely related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: @fectin I think I found the relevant bit. If not, happy to delete again :)

Comment: A related Q&A on MSO (referenced by NautArch above): [Posting the same content on Stack Overflow and Medium.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386059/1478931)